# How to make object childs the same length as maximal child

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lodash

I have such json structure:

```
  {
    "maxPageIndex":1,
    "totalItems":1,
    "currentPageIndex":1,
    "currentPage":[
        {"id":1,"name":"Hummer","compareItems":
            [{"companyId":1,"companyName":"Makoto","compareItemId":10,"compareItemName":"MyHummer"},
            {"companyId":3,"companyName":"Boshst","compareItemId":11,"compareItemName":"Hummer tools"}]
        },
        {"id":2,"name":"Refrigerator","compareItems":
            [{"companyId":1,"companyName":"LeGe","compareItemId":12,"compareItemName":"iRefrigerator"},
             {"companyId":2,"companyName":"Condi","compareItemId":13,"compareItemName":"Refrigerator P48"},
             {"companyId":3,"companyName":"Boshst","compareItemId":14,"compareItemName":"Refrigerator N1"},
             {"companyId":4,"companyName":"Atlanta","compareItemId":15,"compareItemName":"_Refrigerator"},
             {"companyId":5,"companyName":"ChinWeui","compareItemId":16,"compareItemName":"Refrigerator super"}]
        },
        {"id":3,"name":"eBook","compareItems":
            [{"companyId":2,"companyName":"Condi","compareItemId":17,"compareItemName":"iBook"}]
        }
  ]}
```

And main trouble that i should display in table same structure...

I mean for every item in currentPage i'm displaying in table compareItems. BUT! there are not the same length, and my table is like stairs, and i need to make it the same size, i mean that for example 
max length is in `Refrigerator` object (5), and Hummer&eBook compareItems should be 5 length too (just emty object with company data with sorting via Id).

As result i need such table:

```
  {
    "maxPageIndex":1,
    "totalItems":1,
    "currentPageIndex":1,
    "currentPage":[
        {"id":1,"name":"Hummer","compareItems":
            [{"companyId":1,"companyName":"LeGe","compareItemId":10,"compareItemName":"MyHummer"},
            {"companyId":2,"companyName":"Condi"},
            {"companyId":3,"companyName":"Boshst","compareItemId":11,"compareItemName":"Hummer tools"},
            {"companyId":4,"companyName":"Atlanta"},
            {"companyId":5,"companyName":"ChinWeui"}]
        },
        {"id":2,"name":"Refrigerator","compareItems":
            [{"companyId":1,"companyName":"LeGe","compareItemId":12,"compareItemName":"iRefrigerator"},
             {"companyId":2,"companyName":"Condi","compareItemId":13,"compareItemName":"Refrigerator P48"},
             {"companyId":3,"companyName":"Boshst","compareItemId":14,"compareItemName":"Refrigerator N1"},
             {"companyId":4,"companyName":"Atlanta","compareItemId":15,"compareItemName":"_Refrigerator"},
             {"companyId":5,"companyName":"ChinWeui","compareItemId":16,"compareItemName":"Refrigerator super"}]
        },
        {"id":3,"name":"eBook","compareItems":
            [{"companyId":1,"companyName":"LeGe"},
            {"companyId":2,"companyName":"Condi","compareItemId":17,"compareItemName":"iBook"},
            {"companyId":3,"companyName":"Boshst","compareItemId":11,"compareItemName":"Hummer tools"},
            {"companyId":4,"companyName":"Atlanta"},
            {"companyId":5,"companyName":"ChinWeui"}]
        }
  ]}
```

Is it a little bit clear?)

And main goal: i'm a beginner in js, and i wrote such function to do this (i'm using lodash lib):

```
    ctrl.companys = [];

  ctrl.products = /*data from question*/

  _.each(ctrl.products.currentPage, function (rootEl) {
    _.each(rootEl.compareItems, function (compareItemsElement) {
      if (!_.some(ctrl.companys, {Id: compareItemsElement.companyId}) && !_.isUndefined(compareItemsElement.companyId)){
        ctrl.companys.push({Id: compareItemsElement.companyId, Name: compareItemsElement.companyName});
      }
    });
  });

  ctrl.companys = _.sortBy(ctrl.companys, 'Id');

  _.each(ctrl.products.currentPage, function (rootEl, rootElIndex) {
    _.each(rootEl.compareItems, function (compareItemsElement, compareItemsElementIndex) {
      _.each(ctrl.companys, function (company, companyIndex) {
        if (!_.some(rootEl.compareItems, {companyId: company.Id})){
          ctrl.products.currentPage[rootElIndex].compareItems.push({companyId: company.Id, compareItemName: '-'});
          ctrl.products.currentPage[rootElIndex].compareItems = _.sortBy(ctrl.products.currentPage[rootElIndex].compareItems, 'companyId');
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

and it works...
but!
i think that this code is to ugly... Maybe there is a better way of doing that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is requesting a code review of working code. This question should instead be posted on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/